# Запретить чужому сайту вставлять картинки с моего сайта

Tags: .htaccess, php

Добрый день! Встал вопрос, как запретить чужому сайту использовать графику

```
<img src="Мой сайт" />
```

с моего сайта. Чужим сайтом, в данном случае будет любой сайт, в чьём названии нет слова *test*.

```
test.ru - Можно
ad.test.ru  - Можно
test.adawd.dwad.ru - Можно
и т.п...
```

Помогите пожалуйста, искал в интернете, но решение не подходит, так как в данном случае нужно отклонять сайты, где нет слова *test*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*test.* [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Как-то так наверно.

Comment: Во втором RewriteRule **!** не нужен.

Comment: @ReinRaus ну а вроде как "если нет совпадения test". Или как оно расшифровывается?

Comment: Верно, простите. Туплю.